# Print char[] to messagebox

Tags: visual-c++

I am taking the URL value from DocumentComplete and try to copy it to `testDest[256]`
Here is my code:

```
char *p= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(url->bstrVal);

for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(p); i++)
{
  testDest[i] = p[i];   
}
```

My question is, how can I print the `testDest` value on a messagebox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to create a message box is this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, testDest, "some title", 0);
```

If you already have a window and you want to associate the message box with that window, just change the first parameter from `NULL` to the window handle.

Also, if you're using Unicode, you should convert your `char []` to `TCHAR []` or otherwise call the ANSI version (`MessageBoxA`) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
CString cstring( testDest);
AfxMessageBox(testDest);
```